# Are there multiple implementations of Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript

Are there different implementations of `Uint8Array`? This chunk of code behaves differently in Safari and Chrome/FF:

```
var x = new Uint8Array(3);
x.fill(128);    // Safari 9: "TypeError: x.fill is not a function. (In 'x.fill(128)', 'x.fill' is undefined)"
console.log(x); // Chrome 47 and FF 43 print "[128, 128, 128]"
```

I'm confused by differing online descriptions of `Uint8Array`. Mozilla Developer Network describes the `fill()` method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill . But Java Scripture makes no mention of `fill()` as a method: http://www.javascripture.com/Uint8Array .

How can I initialize a `Uint8Array` in Safari?

What am I missing here?

Comment: take look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/fill

Comment: @RolandStarke thanks! I hadn't noticed that fill() is unsupported in Safari. I guess the only alternative is to initialize the array "manually", in a loop.

Comment: @jtbullitt: Use a polyfill that adds the method for Safari.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks. I'm not sure exactly how to do that, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @jtbullitt: You can simply copy over the [polyfill for Array::fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill)

Comment: @Bergi: Many thanks for the link! I'm brand new to polyfills and am struggling to get that code to work as I'd expect. Think I'll post a new question...